# 'SearchForm' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, datefield

I'm trying to create SearchForm with DateField, but form don't see attribute 'get', when I send data method="post". Where is error?

**forms.py**

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):

datee = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'],
    widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(format="%Y-%m-%d"))
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    search_form = search(request)
    context = {'search_form': search_form}
    return render(request, 'name/index.html', context)

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #Do something for examlpe
            HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("name:second"))
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
    search_form = form
    return search_form
```

**index.html**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'name:search' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ search_form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

But I'm getting this **log** and don't understand where is error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/search_result

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.3

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py" in __call__
  97.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response
  26.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /search_result
Exception Value: 'SearchForm' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django view should return httpresponse object. But your search view return form object instead. You can rewrite serch view to something like this to fix error:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #Do something for examlpe
            HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("name:second"))
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
    context = {} 
    context['search_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'name/index.html', context)
```

Comment: Oh thanks, that's working. But why when in form I use this service = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Service.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select) it work without httpresponse object?

Comment: @McRain26 probably your form is not valid in this case and return search_form is never reaced.

Answer (score 0):

`Form` isn't supposed to have `get`, `post` or other `dispatch`ed HTTP verb-matching methods as it's there to represent data and operate on it (more specifically, conveniently delegate any meaningful actions -- i.e. any other than validation and cleaning -- to the underlying infrastructure), not fulfill HTTP request -- the latter is the view's responsibility.

Your `search` view returns a `SearchForm` instance when it must return an `HttpResponse`-compatible object instead, and this is where the error comes from (note the `if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:`).

To fix this, make sure to `return render(request, 'name/index.html', {'form': search_form})` from the `search` view.